# Define an equivalence relation on the set A={a,b,c,d} such that the equivalence classes are {a,b,c} and {c}

Tags: algebra-precalculus, equivalence-relations

Define an equivalence relation on the set A={a,b,c,d} such that the equivalence classes are {a,b,c} and {c}

Hello, sorry if the problem is very trivial, but I'm just learning and I have a question.
They ask me to have these equivalence classes
[x_{1}]={a,b,c}
[x_{2}]={c}
that is, in my set R I must have R={(x_{1},a),(x_{1},b),(x_{1},c),(x_{2},c)}
certain?

So, for it to be equivalent, I must have R=(a,a),(b,b),(c,c))
and do the same for symmetry and transitivity.
but in that case I will have more equivalence relations right?
[a]={a} for example.
Or am I misunderstanding everything?
Could you please explain me, thank you very much.

Comment: $c$ can't be in two equivalence classes simultaneously.  Did you mean $\{a, b, c\}$ and $\{d\}$?

Comment: @L.F. That's what my exercise says: c so I must do 2 equivalence relations one for each one? thanks

Comment: The exercise must be wrong. The set of equivalence classes produces a partition of the set over which the equivalence is defined. $\{\{a,b,c\},\{c\}\}$ isn't a partition : neither does it cover $\{a,b,c,d\}$, nor does it consist of disjoint sets. I don't think your understanding is way off, but you will need some more insight to complete this question.

Comment: Note that $d$ must be in an equivalence class since $d\sim d$ at least.

Comment: @L.F. okei thanks What if they asked for {a,b,c} and {d}? How would the equivalence relation be? pls :C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalence classes of an equivalence relation on $A$ will be a partition of $A$. Therefore $\{a,b,c\}$ and $\{c\}$ cannot be the equivalence classes of any equivalence relation on $A$ (since both sets contain $c$).

If you meant to write $\{a,b,c \}$ and $\{d\}$, then this would be a partition of $A$. In which case you could define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $A$ by $x \sim y$ if they are in the same part of the partition.